# MySQL add and subtract to a total sum, based on content of a second column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to do a summation of a column that considers a second columns content?

What I want is something like the second statement:

```
SELECT * FROM theTable;

+------------+-------------+
|     type   |     value   |
+------------+-------------+
|  plusitive |      11     |
+------------+-------------+
|   negative |       7     |
+------------+-------------+
|   negative |       3     |
+------------+-------------+

SELECT SUM_BASED_ON_WHETHER_type_IS_plusitive_OR_negative(value) FROM theTable;

+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|     SUM_BASED_ON_WHETHER_type_IS_plusitive_OR_negative(value)  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 1                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So the string 'plusitive' would mean multiply value with 1 and 'negative' would mean multiply value with -1 before adding to sum.

Anyone know how to do it? I know that table layout is not optimal for the task, but altering it is not an option. 
A solution would be implemented in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression inside your aggregate function to determine if the value is positive or negative:

```
select
  sum(case `type`
        when 'plusitive' then value
        when 'negative' then value * -1 end) Total
from theTable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1ac5/2)

Comment: Man, can you please tell me how to do that if there are three of types? In the example only two types.

Comment: In my case, first I want to count the total of two type `type_a + type_b` and then reduce it to the third type `- type_c`

Comment: @klaudia My suggestion would be to post a new question with the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM(`value`)
                FROM theTable
                WHERE `type` = 'plusitive'
              )
            , 0)
    - 
    COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM(`value`)
                FROM theTable
                WHERE `type` = 'negative'
              )
            , 0)
    AS Total ;
```